# Close other Modal before opening a new one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have the state of modal visiblity like the following

```
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState({
    supplierMenu: false,
    warehouseMenu: false,
    tagsMenu: false,
    storesMenu: false,
    labelModal: false,
  });
```

Now i have a function which basically toggle visibility state of the model.

```
const toggleModal = (modal) => {
    setOpenModal({ ...openModal, [modal]: !openModal[modal] });
  };
```

and i call for opening and closing of modal like this

```
() => toggleModal("supplierMenu")
```

Now, i am stuck.I want to change the modal state of all the modals to be false before opening the new one.something like this

```
 const toggleModal = (modal) => {
        //Close all modals, set all modal values to false then open a new one
        setOpenModal({ ...openModal, [modal]: !openModal[modal] });
      };
```

Please suggest.Thanks

Comment: show jsx code as well

Answer (score 0):

`import {map,values} from "lodash"`

This should work:

```
const statesKeys = {
    supplierMenu: "supplierMenu",
    warehouseMenu: "warehouseMenu",
    tagsMenu: "tagsMenu",
    storesMenu: "storesMenu",
    labelModal: "labelModal",
}
```

Toggle Modal :

```
const toggleModal = (modalKeyArray) => {
        const _state = map(modalKeyArray, modal => ({
                [modal]: !openModal[modal]
            }); setOpenModal({
                ...openModal,
                ..._state
            });
        };
```

To Toggle One Modal use
`() => toggleModal([statesKeys.supplierMenu])`

To Toggle All,
use
`toggleModal(values(stateKeys))`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable called initialState outside of your component . And use it to toggle the values.

```
const initialState = {
  supplierMenu: false,
  warehouseMenu: false,
  tagsMenu: false,
  storesMenu: false,
  labelModal: false,
};

const YourComponent = () => {

const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(initialState);

const toggleModal = (modal) => {
  setOpenModal(prevModalState => ({ ...initialState, [modal]: !prevModalState[modal] }));
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by making the copy of the state and do manipulation first and then update the state

```
  const openModalCopy = { ...openModal };
    const nextValue = !openModalCopy[modal];
    Object.keys(openModalCopy).forEach((key) => (openModalCopy[key] = false));
    openModalCopy[modal] = nextValue;
    setOpenModal(openModalCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you've defined your state. Instead of storing booleans for each modal, if your use case is to keep only one modal open at any given point, you can store the modal name in your state as string instead.

Something on the lines of this:

```
// state
const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState("");

// Toggle modal function
const toggleModal = (modalName) => {
  if (modalName) {
    setOpenModal(modalName)
  }
}

const closeAllModals = () => {
  setOpenModal("")
}

// trigger modal
<Button onClick={() => toggleModal("supplierMenu")} />

// how to show the modal
{openModal === "supplierMenu" && <SupplierMenuModal />}
```

This way you will always have only one modal open at any time and you will not have to worry about additional logic to close all other modals. And when you want to close all modals just call `closeAllModals()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a default state for the modals

```
const defaultState = {
  supplierMenu: false,
  warehouseMenu: false,
  tagsMenu: false,
  storesMenu: false,
  labelModal: false,
}
```

and then create your state

```
const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(defaultState);
```

Now, if you do this

```
const toggleModal = modal => setOpenModal({ ...defaultState, [modal]: !openModal[modal] });
```

this should ideally set all the modals to `false` first and then sets the selected modal to either `true/false` based on our selection.